# Will a pooled coefficient be bounded by the coefficients from the group regressions?

Tags: multiple-regression, least-squares, pooling

Consider the linear regression model,

$y = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_1 + \beta_2x_2 + u, u \sim N(0, \sigma^2 )$

If we estimate the model twice using OLS on two mutually exclusive groups (say, group 1 and group 2) and then estimate the same model using the pooled sample of group 1 and group 2, should the $\hat{\beta_1}$ from the pooled regression be bounded by the $\hat{\beta_1}$'s we obtain by estimating the model on each group separately?

My intuition tells me no, but any form of proof/evidence is eluding me.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: See http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=Simpson%27s+paradox.

Comment: In all of the examples I see of Simpsons Paradox, the pooled estimates are still bounded by the estimates obtained by looking at each group separately.

My question isn't about comparing $\hat{\beta_1}$ and $\hat{\beta_2}$ in each sample... but comparing $\hat{\beta_1}$ across samples.

Comment: When dealing only with means, it will necessarily be the case that pooled means lie within the range of group means. This result does not extend to slopes. I found the duplicate by narrowing the search to regression examples; the answer there presents exactly the kind of evidence you seek, I believe.